# Подгрузка данных в нужную структуру

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

На сайте есть скрипт, который постоянно подгружает записи в таблицу(table) из БД.

```
 setInterval(function(){ 
 $.ajax({
            url: "for_db.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {refresh:true}, // Передаем данные для записи
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                if (result){ 
                    $('.rows tr').remove();
                    $('.rows').append(function(){
                        var res = '';
                        for(var i = 0; i < result.ordersbuy.total.length; i++){
                            res += '<tr><td>' + result.ordersbuy.id[i] + '</td><td>' + result.ordersbuy.price[i] + '</td><td>' + result.ordersbuy.amount[i] + '</td><td>' + result.ordersbuy.total[i] + '</td></tr>';
                        }
                            return res;
                    });
                    console.log(result);
                }else{
                    alert(result.message);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
 }, 3000);   

});
```

Но на сайте есть специальная "таблица" для ордеров, которая выглядит следующим образом:

```
<div class="orders__table">
                                    <div class="orders__table-row">
                                        <div class="orders__table-pair">11111</div>
                                        <div class="orders__table-buy">BUY</div>
                                        <div class="orders__table-amount">0.05623523</div>
                                        <div class="orders__table-price">0.1023463<span></span></div>
                                        <div class="orders__table-time">12:30:01</div>
                                        <div class="orders__table-status">Open</div>
                                        <div class="orders__table-close">
                                            <img src="img/icons/orders__close.png">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

И я не могу понять, как переписать код, чтобы ордера подгружались в нужную таблицу

Comment: На сколько я вижу у вас ajax формирует список из 4 колонок, а у вас тут больше, куда вы хотите чтобы дописывалось прям в тег `orders__table`?

Comment: @Manitikyl именно, колонки, который не достает я заполню чуть позже, пока из можно оставить пустыми или заполнить какими-нибудь символами

Comment: А у вас сейчас все работает только выводит не туда куда нужно, так?

Comment: @Manitikyl все верно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда попробуйте так:

```
if (result){ 
    $('.orders__table').html(function(){
        var res = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < result.ordersbuy.total.length; i++){
            res += '<div class="orders__table-row">' +
            '<div class="orders__table-pair">' + result.ordersbuy.id[i] + '</div>' + 
            '<div class="orders__table-buy">' + result.ordersbuy.price[i] + '</div>' + 
            '<div class="orders__table-amount">' + result.ordersbuy.amount[i] + '</div>' +
            '<div class="orders__table-price">' + result.ordersbuy.total[i] + '</div>' + 
            '<div class="orders__table-time"></div>' + 
            '<div class="orders__table-status"></div>' + 
            '<div class="orders__table-close"><img src="img/icons/orders__close.png"></div>' +
            '</div>';
        }
        return res;
    });
    console.log(result);
} else {
    alert(result.message);
}
```

P.S. Важно чтобы `<div class="orders__table">` имел закрывающий его `</div>`, а то в вашем вопросе его не видать.

Comment: Ордера не появляются, просто пустота

Comment: @Midnight Ваш изначальный удалился и больше ничего не появляется? Может ничего и не приходит? что там в консольке?

Comment: В network {"ordersbuy":{"id":["161","161","161","161","161","161","161","161","161","161","161"],"price":["4","400","78","15","9","5","55","45","1","5","78"],"amount":["4","100","78","15","9","5","55","54","1","5","78"],"total":["16","40000","6084","225","81","25","3025","2430","1","25","6084"]}}

Comment: @Midnight там в консольке полюбому должны быть ошибки, что пишет?

Comment: В консоли так же просто поток значений :
amount
:
(11) ["4", "100", "78", "15", "9", "5", "55", "54", "1", "5", "78"]
id
:
(11) ["161", "161", "161", "161", "161", "161", "161", "161", "161", "161", "161"]
price
:
(11) ["4", "400", "78", "15", "9", "5", "55", "45", "1", "5", "78"]
total
:
(11) ["16", "40000", "6084", "225", "81", "25", "3025", "2430", "1", "25", "6084"]

Comment: @Midnight нашел ошибку, подправил, попробуйте теперь еще раз.

Comment: Сейчас работает, спасибо!

Comment: Не могли бы помочь еще с 1 вопросом?

Comment: @Midnight что за вопрос?

Comment: Можете дать скайп?

Comment: @Midnight такой-же как и логин тут